# Azure log analytics with Serilog stopped logging (MVC Core)

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core-mvc, serilog, azure-log-analytics

I have a pretty simple MVC Core 2.2 application that is utilizing Serilog and serilog-sinks-azure-analytics (https://github.com/saleem-mirza/serilog-sinks-azure-analytics) to pipe application logs to an Azure log analytics workspace. The implementation looks like this in Program.cs

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var workspaceId = Configuration["AzureLogging:workspaceId"];
            var authenticationId = Configuration["AzureLogging:authenticationId"];
            var logName = Configuration["AzureLogging:logName"];

            //Configure Serilog to add Azure Logging
            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .WriteTo.AzureAnalytics(
                    workspaceId: workspaceId, 
                    authenticationId: authenticationId,
                    logName: logName
                )
                .MinimumLevel.Information()
                .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Warning)
                .MinimumLevel.Override("System", LogEventLevel.Warning)
                .CreateLogger();

            CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }
```

It collected logs for all of day then apparently stopped as when i query the last few hours via the log analytics workspace it returns nothing. If I run a query for the last 7 days I get a count of 350 records which is interesting.

The documentation for the sink project states that the logBufferSize is 25,000 entries by default so it doesn't seem like I am hitting that.

I would appreciate any suggestions on how to diagnose where my logs are or why it might be failing.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is **a limit of about 500 custom fields per log analytics workspace**.

Go to Azure portal > `Log Analytics workspace` > `advanced settings` > `Data` -> `Custom fields for the current field count` and check the count.

You could use  [`Serilog.Sinks.AzureAnalytics`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Serilog.Sinks.AzureAnalytics/2019.1.20). This sink accepts an option parameter `flattenObject` dictating if object properties should be flatten out when exporting to Azure. Setting it to false will retain complex object structure in `LogProperties` property.

For more details, you could refer to this [issue](https://github.com/saleem-mirza/serilog-sinks-azure-analytics/issues/42#issuecomment-456006965).

Comment: Thank you for answering. It is currently showing that I am only using 118 fields.